# Questions regarding the use of Requests Futures for accessing REST URLs

Tags: python, asynchronous, http, signal-handling

This is a much simplified version of the real code focusing just on the handling of Futures from [Requests Futures](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-futures).

I have a few questions:

1. I had to implement my own version of `as_completed` because the data handlers may add more Futures to `_pending`. Is this a decent way to handle the problem, or is there another approach?
2. Is `stop` sufficient to handle `KeyboardInterrupt` in all cases? It has worked well in my limited testing. I found it hard to find a solution via Google.
3. Is my rate limiting solution OK or is there a better approach? It is not about the number of concurrent connections but about the number of connections per second.

```
import argparse
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import requests
from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession
import time

def background_callback(sess, resp):
    # parse the json storing the result on the response object
    if resp.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        resp.data = resp.json()
    else:
        resp.data = None

class JSONRetriever(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)
        self._session = FuturesSession(executor=self._executor)
        self._pending = {}

    def fetch(self, url):
        future = self._session.get(url,
                                   background_callback=background_callback)
        self._pending[future] = url

    def drain(self):
        # Look for completed requests by hand because in the real code
        # the responses my trigger further URLs to be retrieved so
        # self._pending is modified. New requests being added really
        # confused as_completed().
        for future in [f for f in self._pending if f.done()]:
            url = self._pending[future]
            del self._pending[future]

            response = future.result()
            response.raise_for_status()
            if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
                print response.data
                # real code would handle data possibly adding more requests
            else:
                # the real code is smarter, this is just for CR
                raise Exception("FIXME: unhandle response")

    def finish(self):
        while self._pending:
            self.drain()
            if self._pending:
                time.sleep(1)

    def stop(self):
        for i in self._pending:
            try:
                i.cancel()
            except Exception as e:
                sys.stderr.write("Caught: " + str(e) + "\n")

        self._executor.shutdown()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Perform all REST calls")
    parser.add_argument("--delay", type=int, default=0)
    parser.add_argument("urls", nargs="+")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    retriever = JSONRetriever()

    try:
        for url in args.urls:
            retriever.fetch(url)
            if args.delay > 0:  # may need a delay to rate limit requests
                time.sleep(args.delay)
                retriever.drain()  # clear any requests that completed while asleep

        retriever.finish()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        retriever.stop()
```

Comment: Sean, do you not find the requests-futures a bit slow? For example [I can't get an improvement over mulitprocessing.Pool()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747235/python-requests-asynchronous-threading-etc) and some people have suggested tornado instead.

Comment: I have never needed blazing speed.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 1):

Nice code, clearly written.

I understand the rate limiting requirement.
Having the `drain()` call within the loop doesn't seem like the caller's responsibility, better to let the BG callback handle it, or defer until `finish()` as written, which does make sense. Each url fetch could take more or less than the delay time. So this seems to be a bug / wart still lurking within the code.

Comment: This was extracted from something I wrote while working on a REST client where the server sent back "not ready yet" responses. There was behavior that lead me to the `drain()` call but 3 years later I no longer remember what it was. There was definitely a wart but the API was dealing with has since been radically overhauled so I cannot dredge up the issue any longer. Thanks for looking at my post.